# C #: JSON.stringify и валидация JSON Schema

Tags: javascript, c#, .net, json, парсер

Сейчас я использую Json.NET, но у него "слишком строгая" валидация чисел. Загвоздка в том, что JSON.stringify не видит разницы между number и integer, ибо для javascript её в принципе не существует, т.е. 1.0 == 1.

Итого, если schema будет ожидать тип "number"

```
{
  "type": "object",
  "properties": {
    "field": {
      "type": "number"
    }
  }
}
```

а прийдет integer

```
{
  "field":1//it is 1.0 after JSON.stringify
}
```

то валидация вывалит ошибку, что правильно, но.. как же тогда делать?

Да, правильнее всего будет использовать schema и при формировании сообщения, вместо JSON.stringify, но не имею возможности проделать такой трюк на всех клиентах.

Уточню: мне нужно засетить в дробь int, а не наоборот.

PS: Я не привязан к JSON.Net, живу на .net 3.5.

**UPD**: Добавлен пример:

```
using Newtonsoft.Json;
using Newtonsoft.Json.Schema;

public class JSSchemaTest {
    class TestClass
    {
        public float field = 20;
    }
    JsonSchemaGenerator generator = new JsonSchemaGenerator();
    JsonSerializer serializer = new JsonSerializer();
    public void Run () {
        JsonSchema schema = generator.Generate(typeof(TestClass));
        JsonTextReader reader = new JsonTextReader(new System.IO.StringReader("{field: 2}"));
        JsonValidatingReader validatingReader = new JsonValidatingReader(reader);
        validatingReader.Schema = schema;
        TestClass res = serializer.Deserialize<TestClass>(validatingReader);
    }
}
```

Результат будет ожидаемым:

> JsonSchemaException: Invalid type.Expected Float but got Integer.

**UPD**: Вопрос решен (см. ответ ниже), но в дополнение еще скажу, что в старой версии JSON.Net это можно исправить очень маленькой правкой. В файле JsonSchemaGenerator ищем это место:

```
internal static bool HasFlag(JsonSchemaType? value, JsonSchemaType flag)
```

И меняем тамтешний return на свой:

```
return (flag == JsonSchemaType.Integer && value == JsonSchemaType.Float) ? true : ((value & flag) == flag);
```

Comment: Интересно. А покажите минимальный пример падающего кода, а?

Comment: Добавил в вопрос.

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (галка напротив выбранного ответа).

Comment: Да, да, конечно)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вы используете устаревшую версию библиотеки. Валидация была выгружена в отдельный nuget-пакет [Newtonsoft.Json.Schema](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Newtonsoft.Json.Schema/), новая версия оттуда работает нормально.

Исправленный пример:

```
using Newtonsoft.Json;
using Newtonsoft.Json.Schema;
using Newtonsoft.Json.Schema.Generation;

public class JSSchemaTest
{
    class TestClass
    {
        public float field = 20;
    }
    JSchemaGenerator generator = new JSchemaGenerator();
    JsonSerializer serializer = new JsonSerializer();

    public void Run()
    {
        JSchema schema = generator.Generate(typeof(TestClass));
        JsonTextReader reader = new JsonTextReader(new System.IO.StringReader("{field: 2}"));
        JSchemaValidatingReader validatingReader = new JSchemaValidatingReader(reader);
        validatingReader.Schema = schema;
        TestClass res = serializer.Deserialize<TestClass>(validatingReader);
    }
}
```

Используемые версии: Json.NET 8.0.2, Json.NET Schema 2.0.2. Обратите внимание на изменённые имена классов!

---

У библиотеки `Newtonsoft.Json.Schema`, кстати, есть отдельная лицензия для коммерческого использования, в отличие от бесплатной `Newtonsoft.Json`. Для некоммерческого использования обе библиотеки бесплатны.

Comment: Таки да, есть большая вероятность, что версия мне старая попалась.

Comment: Спасибо, Ваш пример отлично работает в .net 4.5

Comment: А есть способ сказать NuGet установить последнюю поддерживаемую версию пакета? В моем случае, чтобы подтянулась самая последняя для .net 3.5

Comment: @Alster: Если я правильно помню, когда вы ставите nuget-пакет без точного указания версии, он ставит последнюю версию, доступную под ваш target framework. У меня под 3.5 поставились (и работают) те же версии 8.0.2/2.0.2.

Comment: @Alster: Хм, вот [этот вопрос](http://stackoverflow.com/q/31981618/276994) наводит на мысль, что не всё так просто, и nuget таки ставит просто последнюю версию. Если это действительно так, придётся подбирать версию вручную :( Но по крайней мере для Json.NET+Schema последняя версия работает под 3.5.

Comment: Извините, ошибся: да, на 3.5 все работает, спасибо)

Comment: @Alster: Пожалуйста!